# How to style object when the user clicks it

Tags: html, css

In css for the links I can style the as before user clicks and after user clicks. But how can I do this for simple text or an object that when a user clicks that object then change its color.
For Example

```
<style>
.object:onmouseclick {
background-color:green;
padding:5px; 
}
</style>
```

What we have to write in place of `onmouseclick`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were styling a link you would use `:active` or `:focus` but as you're using this on a dom element, you would have to use jQuery to add a class to the clicked item and apply the style through that class...

```js
$('.object').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
.object {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 300px;
  color: orange;
}
.object.clicked {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="object">
  <h1>The Mutants Are Revolting</h1>
  <p>Bender?! You stole the atom. That's the ONLY thing about being a slave. I am Singing Wind, Chief of the Martians. Anyhoo, your net-suits will allow you to experience Fry's worm infested bowels as if you were actually wriggling through them.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`button:active` or `button:focus` should do the trick.

```css
a {
  background-color: red;
}

a:active {
  background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<a href="">myButton</a>
```

Comment: But what about a text. How can i do this for text.

Answer (score 0):

and optionally

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.object{
   background:green;
   padding:5px; 
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

input{
    display: none;
}
label{
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
input:checked ~ label{    
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #00f url(http://www.pubzi.com/f/sm-chess-horse.png) no-repeat center center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="object">
     <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="checkbox" />  
        <label for="c1"></label>
</div>
```